# ArrayList Own type to String?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Hello How do I convert in a `ArrayList<>` something to String I will show you my code I am really bad a at explaining stuff sorry:

```
ArrayList<HerniObjekt> batoh = new ArrayList<>();

public void pridej(HerniObjekt objekt)
{
    batoh.add(objekt);
}

public void vypis()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mas v Inevtari "+batoh.);
}
```

And I would like to convert the HerniObject to String how do I do that? thanks for your help.

Comment: And what does `HerniObekt` look like? Which String you would like to get from each object? And finally, what have you tried?

Comment: HenriObject is a class where all the the other classes like NPC abstract from it the class HerniObject: `package javagame;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class HerniObjekt {
    int y;
    int x;
    int smerx;
    int smery;
    int rychlost;
    
    public abstract void krok();
    public abstract void vykresli(Graphics g);

}` and I tried HenriObject.toString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a string by iterating through the array and adding each element to a `StringBuilder`

e.g. without specifying a separator....

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (HerniObjekt h : batoh) {
   sb.append(h);
}
```

Alternatively, Guava has a [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class.

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("; ").skipNulls();
 . . .
return joiner.join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");
```

In either case [you should override](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) `toString()` in your `HerniObjekt` class

Comment: How do I do that I new to Java? sorry

Answer (score 0):

get the **HerniObjekt** list object and assign it to HerniObjekt object in `for-each loop`

**i.e.**

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(HerniObjekt herni : batoh){
  strBuilder.append(herni);
}
```

Append the **HerniObjekt object value to a StringBuilder** object shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In your class HerniObjekt, you can override the method `public String toString(){}` so it returns what you want to output in String

Answer (score 0):

override toString() method in HerniObject ,then foreach add to arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

For a list you could use HTML markup too.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<html><p>Mas v Inevtari</p><ul>");
for (HerniObjekt herni : batoh) {
    sb.append("<li>").append(herni).append("</li>");
}
sb.append("</ul>");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

The above `append(herni)` will use `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class HerniObjekt{
      int id;

      @Override // Override  this method with meaningful
      public String toString() {
           return "Id=" + this.id ;
      }
}

ArrayList<HerniObjekt> batoh = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (HerniObjekt object: batoh ) {
    strBuilder.append(object.toString());
}

System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());

or

System.out.println(batoh.toString());
```